# How to create a virtual input in windows from an audio stream

Tags: windows, audio, skype, input

Great to find this forum full of knowledge.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an application or other work around to create a virtual input device in windows.

I have a IP cam app on my android phone, that I would like to use for skype webcam. It comes with a port for getting the video feed into skype, and that works great. However, the only audio available, is a OGG stream. Both video and audio work great with media players such as VLC etc, but ot with skype, since skype only works with windows input devices.

Is there such software outthere, in which I could simply name my audio stream address, and pipe that to a virtual input device to allow skype to find it?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but something like [VAC](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) would work. It's designed to pipe audio from a virtual output device to a virtual input device. However, you need to configure your media player (e.g. VLC) to send their output to this virtual output device, since they use the system default by.. default.. If you would like to use this method, I can write out the full instructions. The difference from your requested method is you would need two pieces of software: the media player and the virtual audio drivers (and VAC is not free).

Comment: You should try Voicemeeter, the virtual audio device mixer for windows, typically made to route several audio sources to several audio point (including Skype).

Comment: You want to take an ogg input stream, and output it as a virtual windows audio device?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try ManyCam.  It creates both a virtual webcam and audio source.  Once you install it set Skype to use you Android camera and your ManyCam audio source.  Then go in to the ManyCam control and set its audio source to whatever sound you want.

Comment: Sorry, Manycam does not do OGG stream file input as a media stream.